# What is the difference in exponential of log and ln

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

What is the difference in exponential of log and ln?

For example, `exp(ln(sqrt(2))` and `exp(log(sqrt(2))`

What will be the answer for these expressions?

Comment: "log" means logarithm. Depending on who you are, you mean different things for logarithm. If you are a mathematian, your base is e. If you are an engineer, your base is 10. If you are a computer scientist, your base is 2. The use of "ln" is either by computer scientists or engineers, because their "log" means different from e. But mathematicians use only one log so they only stick to one notation, i.e. "log".

Answer (score 2):

Logarithm for base 10 is called **common logarithm** and is represented by `log`, whereas logarithm for the base *e* is called **natural logarithm** and represented using `ln`. 
 

So, 
 $e^{\ln\sqrt2} = \sqrt2$    (base *e* is used) and
 
$e^{\log\sqrt2} = 1.16243273894$ (approx.)

 Hope that helps.

Comment: It should be precised that it depends a lot on the context and book: many books (from my experience, quite old books) use $\log$ for the logarithm of base $e$ and would write $\log_a$ for another base $a$.
For example, Maple consider $\log$ and $\ln$ are the same and as a function $\log10$ for the base $10$.

Comment: @Taladris agreed. But since the question specifically gives ln and log , thats why I've written common and natural logarithm.

Comment: Yes, usage of both the notation varies by region.